# JavaFx: ComboBox textWrap

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, javafx-8, word-wrap

I am trying to wrap the text in the `ComboBox` but I cannot really manage it.

I need the wrapped text in the editor part, not in the dropdown part of the `comboBox`. I see that the editor is a `TextField`, and its text cannot really be wrapped or?

Is there any trick or solution to have a nicely wrapped text so if I have a really long text I can see it every time?

So instead of displaying the `...` I want the whole text to be displayed.

Code part I don't know if I should add since it is really simple table cell, and a `ComboBox` set as `Graphics`, but if it helps I will edit the question.

**Note:** Setting the colum wider so the text can fit, is not a solution!

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: don't show the combo when not editing?

Comment: Yeah, that would be easy :D Bat unfortunately that is not an option since this is implemented to be much more easier to select a value and avoid unnecessary clicks + the user knows which cells can be edited and which cannot.

Comment: yeah, suspected that wouldn't be an option, had to try, though :)

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to do this but what I do in this situation is use a context menu or double click to open a popup that is used to edit or change the text.

Comment: @Sedrick I don't really get what you would suggest. Here the point is to detect the selectable items and do the selection of an item as easy as possible, I see just complications with context menus and popups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am bit confused about the question. You want to show the wrapped text while editing or while in non edit mode.? Because if you are in editing mode you cannot see ... in text box.
So I assume you are asking for showing the wrapped text after selecting from popup list and the combo is not in edit mode.We can fix that using buttonCell.

If this is what you are not asking for, then a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can help me to look into the actual issue.

Please refer to the below code of how to show the wrapped text.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TableViewComboBoxCell extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();

    private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList(
                    new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                    new Person("Isabella", "Johnson",
                            "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                    new Person("Ethan", "Williams",
                            "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                    new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                    new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private final ObservableList<String> comboList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("First big sentence with very long text to check the text wrap",
            "Second big sentence with very long text to check the text wrap",
            "Third big sentence with very long text to check the text wrap",
            "Fourth big sentence with very long text to check the text wrap");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            if(i%5==0){
                data.add(new Person("Name " + i, "Last " + i, "Mail " + i, comboList.get(0)));
            }else {
                data.add(new Person("Name " + i, "Last " + i, "Mail " + i));
            }
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(650);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol
                .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                        "firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol
                .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                        "lastName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                "email"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> comboCol = new TableColumn<>("Combo");
        comboCol.setMinWidth(200);
        comboCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(
                "combo"));
        comboCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, String> call(TableColumn<Person, String> param) {
                return new TableCell<Person, String>() {
                    private ComboBox<String> combo;

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        getCombo().getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                        if (!empty) {
                            getCombo().setValue(item);
                            setGraphic(getCombo());
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }

                    private ComboBox<String> getCombo() {
                        if (combo == null) {
                            combo = new ComboBox<>();
                            combo.setItems(comboList);
                            combo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, old, newVal) -> {
                                ((Person) getTableRow().getItem()).setCombo(newVal);
                            });
                            combo.setButtonCell(new ListCell<String>() {
                                private Text textLbl;
                                @Override
                                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                    setGraphic(null);
                                    if (!empty) {
                                        getTextLbl().setText(item);
                                        setGraphic(getTextLbl());
                                    }
                                }

                                private Text getTextLbl(){
                                    if(textLbl ==null){
                                        textLbl = new Text();
                                        textLbl.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().subtract(10));
                                    }
                                    return textLbl;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return combo;
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol, comboCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);
        ((StackPane) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;
        private final SimpleStringProperty combo;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this(fName,lName,email,null);
        }

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email, String comboStr) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
            this.combo = new SimpleStringProperty(comboStr);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty emailProperty() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email.set(email);
        }

        public String getCombo() {
            return combo.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty comboProperty() {
            return combo;
        }

        public void setCombo(String combo) {
            this.combo.set(combo);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is as below:

[image]

Comment: my guess (only the OP knows for sure) is that the combo needs to be editable or at least needs to look like being editable - which forces the usage of a TextField which doesn't support wrapping ... unfortunately api, I would say, to have the text input control narrowed down to a textField, could have decided to make it TextInputControl

Comment: Almost works, the problem is, the comboBox doesn't fit automatic to the cell's height, like in your screenshot is, I tried to bind to the cell's `heightProperty()` but after scrolling it is getting even worst. Do you have any other relevant code fragment which you didn't show?

Comment: Here is how it looks like: https://imgur.com/PKO3SU6, after I click on the `comboBox` it is getting resized correctly: https://imgur.com/aBe5mXN

Comment: It happens if there is already a selected value loaded from the model. After selecting a new value it works perfectly.

Comment: Updated the complete demo code. Will check what is  happening if the combo box has a selected value.

Comment: don't re-create the combo on every call to updateItem - they are frequent! Instead create it once (including the custom buttonCell) at instantiation time

Comment: Updated the demo code as per kleopatra's comment. However the issue of improper alignment of button cell on load still exists. Investigating...

Comment: was meant as a general note (not anything that fixes the glitch), should have been clearer :)

Comment: and another general note: don't use PropertyValueFactory if the data exposes properties ..

Comment: This glitch is really interesting and annoying, I cannot manage to fit the ComboBox in the Cell, it would be so simple if this would work, because as I see the text tries to fill the TableCell not the comboBox's buttoncell.

Comment: I think I found the solution instead of `textLbl.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().subtract(10));` I used `textLbl.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(comboBox.widthProperty().subtract(10));`

Comment: I think I can accept it since you found the way to wrap the text in the comboBox, Thanks for both of you :)

Comment: I am still not clear what makes the difference in binding between ListCell & ComboBox. Anyway good catch,. atleast fixed the issue ;)